# Site returning 404 header to Google, not sure why

Tags: google, googlebot, 404

A Drupal site that works fine for regular users returns a 404 not found error when I try to use the W3C validator on it; it is also not being indexed by Google at all (which is the main issue but I suspect there is a connection). It is a `https://` site with `.htaccess` rule to redirect any `http://` request to `https://`.

I had had it running in Google webmaster tools and thought it was fine, but it turns out I had not added the HTTPS domain. After adding the HTTPS domain it's also returning the header as

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 15 Oct 2012 19:37:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

`robots.txt` just has

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
```

How can I check what the issue is here?

Comment: Did you find why the validator got a 404?

Comment: i had only http in gwt. with https it also shows the 404 header.. no idea why

Comment: I mean, did you try to find, on the server side, why is there this 404? In apache log for example, by enabling more rewrite level log, etc ..

Comment: No idea.. :/ could you elaborate a bit on what methods I might try? I'm usually more just doing development

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but have you looked at your portfolio site with Googlebot user-agent?

Comment: I've noticed that even Web Inspector shows it as 404-Not Found in the Resources section.. somewhere the 404 header is being written but I have no idea how/where/why

Comment: Do you have access to your apache server error logfiles?

Comment: Can you share with us the name of the site?  If I knew the site, I could test it myself.

Answer (score 1):

> A Drupal site that works fine for regular users returns a 404 not found error when I try to use the W3C validator on it

It sounds like you are erroneously sending a "404 Not Found" HTTP response header for all requests, instead of a "200 OK". Regular users will "see" the working page, but the W3C Validator and search engine bots will report an error.

However, without more information about your specific site, this is impossible to answer further.